# Returning URL in json instead of ArrayList

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I want to return a URL reference in a JSON response instead of the result ArrayList in Java.

I know that is possible, but I really forgot the Annotation (and also the lib) to do this.
I've look the [jackson docs](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), [jersey docs](http://jersey.java.net/) and tiring searchs on Google, unsuccessfully.

I have this example class:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String uuid;

    //@JsonMissingAnnotation
    private List<Products> products;
```

And I want to return:

```
    "User": {
        "uuid": "1234",
        "products": "http://mydomain/api/users/1234/products" 
    }
```

Intead of return a full arraylist (that may be unnecessary), I want to return a URL for that Array, and the Product List must be retrive sending a GET to this link.

I see this as a best practices in [Apigee](http://apigee.com/about/api-best-practices) at once.

Regards,

Comment: I would use RESTeasy in combination with Gson. You also have to write a POJO if you need to convert your ArrayList to a single string.

Comment: I know that implementation works in Jersey, RestEASY and Spring 3. I think that is a jackson (or similar) implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer at Jersey's [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e1196):

```
@Ref(value="users/${user.uuid}/products",
  condition="${user.products}")
URI productsRef;
```

This create a URI for lists as I desire, and I hide the List from JSON parsing.

This will result the following JSON:

```
"User": {
        "uuid": "1234",
        "productsRef": "http://mydomain/api/users/1234/products" 
    }
```

.